# Transform three triggers into one

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm trying actually to call 3 stored procedures from 3 different trigerrs on the same table.
Actually i have 3 stored procedures: insert_user(), update_user(), delete_user(). The problem is that i have 3 triggers that are associated with the same table wp_users, the problem is that only one trigger can be associated with one table (if i understand it well). So i'm looking for another solution.

CREATE TRIGGER `user_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `wp_users`
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
       CALL insert_user();
    END;

CREATE TRIGGER `user_update` AFTER INSERT ON `wp_users`
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
       CALL update_user();
    END;

CREATE TRIGGER `user_delete` AFTER INSERT ON `wp_users`
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
       CALL delete_user();
    END;

So my question is how can i transform these 3 triggers into one, so that i have one trigger associated with one table which do the insert, update or delete on the table wp_user ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is it MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server? You've tagged both.

Comment: i'm sorry it is MySql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the correct AFTER clause:

```
CREATE TRIGGER user_insert AFTER INSERT ON wp_users FOR EACH ROW BEGIN CALL insert_user(); END;

CREATE TRIGGER user_update AFTER UPDATE ON wp_users FOR EACH ROW BEGIN CALL update_user(); END;

CREATE TRIGGER user_delete AFTER DELETE ON wp_users FOR EACH ROW BEGIN CALL delete_user(); END;
```